# From php5.6 to 7.1 Array to string conversion

Tags: php

I have a "Array to string conversion" notice for this line when i upgrade from 5.6 to 7.1 :

```
 $template = $this->$functions[$i]($name, $value);
```

how i could resolve it in order to work with php7.1 ?

UPDATE :

```
protected function getobjectTemplate($name, $value)
    {
        $template = false;
        $functions = [
            'getObjectFormClientTemplate',
            'getObjectFormTemplate',
            'getObjectAirformTemplate',
            'getTypeAirformTemplate',
            'getAirfileTemplate',
            'getTextAirformTemplate',
        ];
        $i = 0;
        while (!$template) {
            $template = $this->$functions[$i]($name, $value);
            ++$i;
        }

        return $template;
    }
```

here the call of the method getobjectTemplate

```
$template = $this->getobjectTemplate($name, $value);
```

Comment: We don't know what's `$functions[$i]`'s code, and what type are `$name` and `$value` variables, can you please add more details?

Comment: somewhere you're trying to convert an array to a string, and you should try to prevent yuor code from doing that. But we can't tell precisely where the problem is, from the minimal code (and total lack of data) provided.

Comment: $name and $value are string data

Comment: That's just the name of the functions called, not their code, can you add the code of the one that causes this notice?

Comment: @Kaddath when i debug the line $template = $this->$functions[$i]($name, $value); make a new php notice

Comment: I made [a little test](https://tio.run/##ZY/BCoMwEETv@YqtLKjoocajln6I9SCyYsBq0GgPxW@3ayC1xUsYknmTGd3qLb9rPpu5r40aejA0mSTAJXwLAKzgBgUkMUgoM76guh3Asx7Ahd8fvZeJVfzh0uGHW7LbWgFGMvPIxnGmE5meydSRqxBo6Km7yhC3aqpu4gB0/LQ3ZdK35fzYSXnIlCWvQMXWayZereoIgss3NQS7@eeTI71AVQY2xQ/3FVGEijtt2wc): you should have the notice show the line of the content of the function called, not at the `$template = $this->$functions[$i]($name, $value);` line. Can you try to remove the `$this->` part to see if it works? `$functions` is a local var in the shown code, not a class property..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most elegant solution but it would work:

```php
protected function getobjectTemplate($name, $value)
    {
        $template = false;
        $functions = [
            'getObjectFormClientTemplate',
            'getObjectFormTemplate',
            'getObjectAirformTemplate',
            'getTypeAirformTemplate',
            'getAirfileTemplate',
            'getTextAirformTemplate',
        ];
        $i = 0;
        while (!$template) {
            $func = [ $this, $functions[$i] ];
            $template = $func($name, $value);
            ++$i;
        }

        return $template;
    }
```

I would probably also go ahead and remove the `while (!template)` condition as it has the potential to make your code enter into an infinite loop. Probably use a better condition like `$i < count($functions)` or even better with something like:

```php
$i = 0;
$funcCount = count($functions);
while(!$template && $i < $funcCount){
   # ...
   ++$i;
}
```

Also, you are returning only the last value from all the functions being called via `return $template`. If you only have to return the last value, why not call only the required function and not have a loop. Not sure, if having a loop is the best approach. Would help if you provided more details of your code.

Comment: You're right about the infinite loop, but I guess the `while (!$template) {` condition is for the loop to stop at the first function that returns a result. To keep this behavior, the corrected version should be `while(!$template && $i < $funcCount){`

Answer (score 3):

This can be one of the solutions. First store the function name in a variable and then use it.

```
while (!$template) {
            $temp=$functions[$i];
            $template = $this->$temp($name,$values);
            ++$i;
 }
```